# How to work with two different types of array in single adapter of grid view

Tags: android, gridview

Let me explain my question , I have a grid view which has to show images from resource folder i.e drawables and from device. So I have made int array for resources images and arraylist for my custom data type for images in device

**Now what it looks like, the array of images from resources**

```
 public static Integer[] mThumbIds = {R.drawable.myImage_1, R.drawable.myImage, R.drawable.myImage,
        R.drawable.myImage};
```

**And array list of my custom data type.**

```
static List<MyDetails> myData = new ArrayList<MyDetails>(myDb.GetAllData());
```

so in short as we know that images in the resources are deal as integers while images in my custom array list has a path of string , this is path which tells where the image is , on my device , so my picasso library gets the image from there

> Now My problem is , I know how to show images from one single array ,
>   and how to set the respective adapter , but in this case I want to
>   show the images coming from my arraylist and also the images from my
>   resource folder.

Do you have any idea , how to achieve this ?

Comment: Every object of MyDetails has a resource drawable and an image path? and you need to show both or what?

Comment: no mThumbIds has resources images , while myData array list has image path from device gallery

Answer (score 0):

```
List all = new Arraylist(mThumbIds);
all.addAll(MyDetails);

getView(int i){
  Object object = m.get(i);
  if(object instanceof Integer){
  //form resource;
     int resid = (int)object;

  }else if(object instanceof MyDetails){
  //from db;
     MyDetails mydetail = (MyDetails)object;
 }

}
```

Comment: looks interesting , let me try this

Comment: Please, add some explanation to the answer.

Comment: @tiny sunlight through your answer I think I have done addition of both array into one list, but tell me how to sort out things in the if structure under you getView demo 

what I am supposed to write 
if(object instanceof Integer){
                //form resource;
                Picasso.with(SuitShowCase.this) //
                            .load("HOW SHOULD I GET INTEGER OUT HERE FROM LIST ") //

Comment: In this way the getview will run two times , How I am supposed to handle that

Comment: What's your meaning?why should the gridview run two times